# realtek driver randomly stops working

Tags: wifi, drivers, realtek

If i do not reboot my computer for on average one to two days, my wifi randomly stops working. After looking at the output of dmesg, i figured that it has something to do with the wifi driver.

This is its output: https://pastebin.com/gnd1Etet

This is my device:

```
can@asuli:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.2
Release:    20.2
Codename:   uma
can@asuli:~$ uname -a
Linux asuli 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: I've had similar behaviour on a realtek chipset which I never managed to get to the bottom of. In the end I pulled the wifi card out and put a replacement (intel) in.  Realtek linux drivers can be a bit flaky because realtek themselves don't tend to publish their own Linux drivers.  That said... The "usual suspects" here are looking around for an alternative driver for the same chipset [eg here](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) and checking other things like ensuring power management is not turning off the device.